# Building wiki on top of a restful application

Tags: web-services, rest, integration, wiki

Does anybody know a wiki engine that can be built on top of a RESTful application?
I have a restful application, that exposes a document resource,
I want the wiki engine to use the REST API to persist the documents, instead of saving them to a DB.
I am also open for suggestions of an open-source wiki engines that can be easily modified to support such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As Wikis were originally designed to work in a standard browser, and most browsers did not support anything except GET and POST, REST is not a concept used a lot on the wiki world. However, nowadays, some wikis (foswiki - the community fork of TWiki for instance) provide you a REST API to it http://foswiki.org/System/CommandAndCGIScripts#rest ).

But you need the opposite: a wiki with a customizable backend (storage) that could be plugged on top of a REST storage service. As wikis with a pluggable backend, I know only of pmwiki http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/PmWiki and foswiki (the open fork of TWiki) http://foswiki.org.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a puzzler.  Wikis in general are more or less the canonical example of a RESTful approach.  The page name names a resource.  What do you want that isn't in, eg, Twiki?

Comment: I want the wiki engine to be the presentation layer, I want my restful application to be the backend data storage, I want the wiki to communicate with my app using the rest ws

Comment: Right.  This still isn't quite making sense.  Consider something like Twiki, or OddMuse, where the resource name is the actual file name.  The URIs are "RESTful", the storage is directly managed by the RESTful URIs.  Do you want something that translates the Wiki URIs to some *other* RESTful back end, like Google AppEngine or the like?

Answer (score 0):

While you could try to find a wiki that can use a REST backend, it may be better to write a small wiki yourself. Because even though a your backend has REST interface, that doesn't  mean you can put some other application in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

dokuwiki does not use a database. It is a filesystem based wiki. I don't know its internal code structure but you might be able to use it as your base.